# second parameter to jQuery's die is a selector string?

Tags: jquery

I ran into a usage of jQuery's die that is either a custom extension or not documented...  According to the jQuery docs, the second parameter should be a method (http://api.jquery.com/die/).  I'm seeing a usage where the second parameter is selector string.  Does anyone know what this does?

```
    $("*").die('click', '.optionsMenu');
```

I'd think its only removing certain click handlers, but not sure precisely what its doing.

Answer (score 3):

It's [not using the parameter](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L977) (since it's not a function), it's the same as calling:

```
$("*").die('click');
```

So it's killing **all** [`.live('click',....)`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) events, I think what they *meant* to do was this:

```
$('.optionsMenu').die('click');
```

Comment: It does use the parameter; `$('*').die('click', '.optionsMenu')` is equivalent to `$('.optionsMenu', $('*')).die('click')` which in turn is equivalent to `$('.optionsMenu').die('click')`. Just check lines 979-980.

Comment: @Tgr - That's just not correct, here's a demo to demonstrate it does *not* work that way: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mHVXQ/